# Why can't I create static final variable in psvm Java?

Tags: java, oop

It will not compile but when I put initalization of variable out of main method it will be ok.

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        static final int x = 2;

        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`static` variable is  loaded when a class gets loaded. But a local variable gets loaded when method gets called (after class gets loaded). 
So when class gets loaded , local variable will not be created by that time

Answer (score 0):

`static final int x = 2;` local variables can't be static that's why compiler complains

Comment: thanks. I didn't know that local variables can't be static

Answer (score 0):

`static` modifier is who is causing problem here.
you cant make a local variable `static` for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables cannot be declared private, public, protected or **static**, delete the `static` keyword.